# Python multiprocessing Pool can't handle large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I'm attempting to use the python multiprocessing package to speed up the pivoting of a series of large dataframes on with dimensions approx. 10k*12k-by-3 --> 10k-by-12k

The dataset is essentially a longform matrix.

This is the code I'm attempting to run:

```
parts = [df1, df2, df3]
pool = mp.Pool(3)
matrices = pool.map(long_to_matrix, parts)
```

This triggers the following error for larger matrices.

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-7ebabe0045b8> in <module>
----> 1 matrices = pool.map(long_to_matrix, parts)

/XXXX/tools/miniconda2/envs/aj_work/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    266         in a list that is returned.
    267         '''
--> 268         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    269
    270     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

/XXXX/tools/miniconda2/envs/aj_work/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

/XXXX/tools/miniconda2/envs/aj_work/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in _handle_tasks(taskqueue, put, outqueue, pool, cache)
    429                         break
    430                     try:
--> 431                         put(task)
    432                     except Exception as e:
    433                         job, idx = task[:2]

/XXXX/tools/miniconda2/envs/aj_work/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py in send(self, obj)
    204         self._check_closed()
    205         self._check_writable()
--> 206         self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
    207
    208     def recv_bytes(self, maxlength=None):

/XXXX/tools/miniconda2/envs/aj_work/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py in _send_bytes(self, buf)
    391         n = len(buf)
    392         # For wire compatibility with 3.2 and lower
--> 393         header = struct.pack("!i", n)
    394         if n > 16384:
    395             # The payload is large so Nagle's algorithm won't be triggered

error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

Does anyone know how I could possible fix this? I actually tried to split the matrices into smaller chunks, but the process of slicing the dataframe actually took longer than the pivot so it wasn't a good option. Is this a bug?

Comment: Have you considered using `dask` or `vaex`?

Comment: Is dask able to multithread or pivot faster than normal pandas? I can give it a try

Comment: Actually dask won't work for me since I'm downloading the data from BigQuery. So that would require a write to file and then a new read

Comment: pivot_table on dask [doc](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.reshape.pivot_table)